# How do I convert MongoDB Date String to Date Object in Jasper Reports?

Tags: java, mongodb, date, jasper-reports

I'm fetching certain records from `MongoDB` which have a column of the type date.

It looks like this: `2015-02-03T11:57:18.968Z`

When I create a *topic* in `JasperReports` I want to convert this into a `Date` type.

`Jasper` identifies this as `String` data type. When I manually change it to `Date` and upload it to `JasperServer` it shows me the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Conversion error, field name: "invoicedate" requested type: "java.util.Date" received type: "java.lang.String" value: "2015-02-03T11:57:18.968Z"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this by saving the date string as a `Date` in `MongoDB`.